# How to convert string value to date value and then call max() or min() on Groovy collection

Tags: json, parsing, groovy, collections

I have a collection that contains Date values in string format. The below code is giving better results except for the properties startDate and endDate are string so min() and max() does not return correct values.
Sample data:

```
{
 "https://dev.example.com/pages/TEST-2": [
    {
      "startDate": "2020-05-16",
      "endDate": "2020-05-17",
      "planItem": {
        "self": "https://dev.example.com/pages/TEST-2",
        "type": "ISSUE"
      },
    },
    {
      "startDate": "2020-05-17",
      "endDate": "2020-05-20",
      "planItem": {
        "self": "https://dev.example.com/pages/TEST-2",
        "type": "ISSUE"
      }
    }
  ],
  "https://dev.example.com/pages/AP-3": [
    {
      "startDate": "2020-05-16",
      "endDate": "2020-05-17",
      "planItem": {
        "self": "https://dev.example.com/pages/AP-3",
        "type": "ISSUE"
      }
    },
    {
      "startDate": "2020-05-27",
      "endDate": "2020-05-27",
      "planItem": {
        "self": "https://dev.example.com/pages/AP-3",
        "type": "ISSUE"
      }
    }
  ],
  "https://dev.example.com/pages/AP-1": [
    {
      "startDate": "2020-05-16",
      "endDate": "2020-05-17",
      "planItem": {
        "self": "https://dev.example.com/pages/AP-1",
        "type": "ISSUE"
      }
    }
  ],
  "https://dev.example.com/pages/AP-4": [
    {
      "startDate": "2020-05-16",
      "endDate": "2020-05-18",
      "planItem": {
        "self": "https://dev.example.com/pages/AP-4",
        "type": "ISSUE"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I convert these String values into Date datatype? Can I do it in the same method call collectEntries? what would be faster solution in this case?

```
def data = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse("data.json" as File)

println(data.collectEntries{ url, plans ->
    [url, [startDate: plans*.startDate.min(), endDate: plans*.endDate.max()]]
}.inspect())
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have a small example for `data.json`?

Comment: Could you please add how the original is not working? This should basically use `String.compareTo` for the date strings and those date strings should sort fine. Please provide the failing example data or please point out, where above code fails.

Comment: The original solution is working as expected. There was some other reason that the original answer was not working which I fixed and got correct result. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With your example, I get the correct results as string comparison does sort the date strings correctly, but assuming you have an example where this fails, you could do:

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def data = new JsonSlurper().parse("data.json" as File)

data.collectEntries{ url, plans ->
    [url, [startDate: plans*.startDate.min { LocalDate.parse(it) }, endDate: plans*.endDate.max { LocalDate.parse(it) }]]
}
```

Comment: Does it parse all the string date values first and then execute min() or another way around? Also can you please explain how it does the whole thing?